# Injecting beans into filter packaged in a shared library

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, servlet-filters, ejb-3.1

I've got an JavaEE6 app with following structure:

```
app.ear
  META-INF
    application.xml
  lib
    commmon-server-lib.jar
  webapp1.war
  webapp2.war
  services-ejb.jar
```

Both webapps have common-server-lib.jar in Class-Path entry of their MANIFEST.MF (skinny war's).

application.xml:

```
<application>
  <module>
    <ejb>services-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>webapp1.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/webapp1</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>webapp2.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/webapp2</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

In `common-server-lib.jar` there is a web filter that should have few EJBs and other CDI managed beans injected. This filter is defined in `web.xml`'s of both webapps.

`common-server-lib.jar` and war's have `beans.xml` in appropriate place.

Now the problem is, that when I try to deploy this app to Glassfish I get errors like this:

```
Class [ Lcom/acme/UserService; ] not found. Error while loading 
    [ class com.acme.filter.MyFilter ]
```

`UserService` service is located in services-ejb.jar

So my question is: what am I doing wrong...? Is there something wrong in defining web components (that use injections for it's dependencies) in a shared library?

**Edit:**

In section 15.5 of JSR-315 (Servlets 3.0 final spec) one can find:

> ```
> In a web application, classes using resource injection will have their annotations
> processed only if they are located in the WEB-INF/classes directory, or if they are
> packaged in a jar file located in WEB-INF/lib.
> ```

I've moved common-server-lib.jar to WEB-INF/lib directories of both webapps but I'm still having same issue ;/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of struggling with this puzzle I've found a solution:

1. Add `web-fragment.xml` to `commmon-server-lib.jar` with my filter
2. Remove filter specification from webapps `web.xml`'s
3. Change maven fonfiguration to remove all jar's from `WEB-INF/lib`
   directory except `commmon-server-lib.jar`
4. Remove `commmon-server-lib.jar` from EAR `/lib` directory